# Is it possible to set custom discord presence/activity/status with discordjs bot commands?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I want to set custom status in discord when the user type a certain command in pm with the bot.
I didn't find anything to do that on https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Anybody knows how to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CUSTOM_STATUS activity type is not available to bots (and therefore, you cannot set a custom status) However, all other activity types should be useable.

You can set the bot's activity directly via [`ClientUser#setActivity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity):

```js
//for example ...
client.user.setActivity("a bunch of commands ", { type: "WATCHING" })
// Watching a bunch of commands
```

**Notes:** "client" is whatever you instantiated your client instance as (`const someVar = new Discord.Client()`). Common alternative name(s) are "bot", "automaton", "discordbot"..etc..

You should place `#setActivity` in an event listener (`client.on("message" ...`, `client.on("ready" ...`), to avoid problems with the client not being logged in yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

My question was not clear i'm sorry, but I need to update the user's status not the bot status, is this possible with the same code?

Comment: No, the `bot` OAuth2 scope does not encompass setting a user's presence data (aside from `ClientUser`). The reason for this is simple: the user does not explicitly consent for this to happen.
 If you feel it is really necessary, you will need `activities.write` for that, see https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for your time